# force TextBox to refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a normal wpf TextBox control bound to a string property. I need the displayed text to be updated immediately after the binding or the .Text property is updated. I have tried

```
((TextBox)sender).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
((TextBox)sender).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

in the TextChanged event handler.

I've tried `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` on the binding. I've tried

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Input,
     new Action(() =>
     {
         statusTextBox.Text = "newValue";
     }));
```

and many different combinations of these. But the text displayed changes only once the method I update the textbox from exits.

XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txBox" Height="150" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AcceptsReturn="True"  VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding TextProperty}"Width="200" />
```

Comment: What does your XAML look like?

Comment: Why are you setting `statusTextBox.Text = "newValue"` when you bound the text to a property?

Comment: Raising a `OnPropertyChanged` event on `TextProperty` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` should be sufficient for this. Have you tried those approaches?

Comment: @Bob It's just one my many tries to get the displayed value to change. Actually I use the binding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your method if it's doing alot of work is probably holding the UI thread () the order of execution). Whatever you are doing in that method - do it in the background thread.

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
                       /// do all your logic here

                       //Update Text on the UI thread 
                       Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( DispatcherPriority.Input,
                      new Action(() => { statusTextBox.Text = "newValue";}));

                       //continue with the rest of the logic that take a long time
                    });
```

Just make sure that if in that method you are touching any UI elements, you do it on the UI thread, otherwise you will get a crash. Another, possibly better way to let UI thread know is to RaisePropertyChanged that you want the binding to know about, instead of directly manipulating the UI element.

Comment: I do use RaisePropertyChanged in my property the textbox is bound to.

Comment: That's great! Then all you have to do is to wrap stuff that hogs your method's chain of execution in the task and update the property that your statusTextBox is bound to there as well. It will update immidiately - before the method is done its exection.

Comment: I found another good solution here: http://dedjo.blogspot.dk/2007/08/how-to-doevents-in-wpf.html

Comment: oh, yeah, that's another way to release the UI thread. I usually use it only when I can't control/do anything else. For example, DataGrid loading slow, so I would separate each row loading and DoEvents() in between, giving it cascading effect for rolling out rows. Here it seems simpler to just use tasks, but it's up to your preferences. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TwoWay binding instead of changing the TextBox's value expicitly and you need to implement the **INotifyPropertyChanged** on the binded data's class.

Comment: Technically he is already using `TwoWay` as it's the default for `TextBox`. But yes the _real_ answer is `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code sequence, it worked for me-

```
Textblock1.Text = "ABC";
System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
MainWindow.InvalidateVisual();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(40);
```

Comment: the question was for an WPF application